# Switching IMAP/POP3 login username from username to username@domain

Tags: postfix, dovecot, centos7

I'm running a CentOS7 server with Postfix, Dovecot, Roundcube, etc.   Right now everything is working.  Users log in and check their mail by their username only.  I would like to alter this so they have to specify their username@theirdomain as the IMAP/POP login to authenticate.   I'm not quite sure where this is specified?   Are there config options in Postfix, Dovecot, or do I simply modify the username in vipw and add the domain as part of the username?  (And if I do that, I guess it means any ssh/telnet/ftp accounts would also have the username changed?)  Please advise, and let me know if changing this may require other modifications elsewhere?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I tested a few things.    I can satisfy one part of this condition by changing the username in the system file to name@domain and I can enable logging in using a fully-qualified e-mail address.  This works for checking mail, but then Postfix doesn't recognize the destination mailbox for incoming mail and gives an error "Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; User unknown in virtual alias table"  -- so one step forward, one step backward...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to just force everyone to append `@example.com` to their e-mail usernames, or are you looking to actually support virtual mail hosting (where different people may have different domains on their usernames)?  If the former, I'd question the utility, but if you're dead-set on it, you could probably tweak some option or another in the dovecot config to make that happen.  On the other hand, if you want to do proper virtual mail hosting, you'll need to setup a virtual mail server, with all that that implies (I like using Postfixadmin for n00b-friendly setups, and recommend following their guide for making the necessary changes to postfix and dovecot to make it all work correctly together), and then do the mail migration (probably hoover it out of the users' local mail spools and dump it wherever you've configured Dovecot to look at it).  A step-by-step on all that would be waaaaaaay too long for a serverfault answer, but you can put the pieces together from existing documentation found via a search engine of your choice, and ask specific questions on SF if you get stuck.

Comment: I don't want to support virtual mail hosting.  I just note that it seems more common than not, when specifying mail login credentials to use: username@domain as the username than just username.   I also run the mail server for multiple domains and I want Roundcube to by default set up the client's appropriate domain when they log in so they don't have to go into preferences and change the base domain to their own.

Comment: I think what I'm asking is very specific and narrow.  If this involves some elaborate setup, I'd like to know, but it could also be a simple fix.  I'm waiting to have someone weigh in who knows for sure.

Comment: Again, this is very specific... my mail system works great by default.. I simply want to know if there's a way to switch between the pop3 login name as name@domain.